# How to receive new token from devise_token_auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

Hi currently I'm using devise_token_auth gem gem for SPA (single page application). I'm using React-redux in front-end and rails at backend. The authentication would be done by sending token to the server on each request. till this every thing was running smoothly:

Problem statement:

The token has to be stored in the browser which makes my app vulnerable

Solution:

Change token on each request. good enough !!!

Problem statement:

But to receieve a new token I have to send user email-id as well as password. which means these two fields has to be stored somewhere in the browser. is it good practice to store user password in browser ??

Or there exist any better approach to do this.. any ideas ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't have to worry about receiving new token. `devise_token_auth` automatically provides you a new token after each validation.[See the documentation devise_auth_token token management](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#about-token-management)

For example: If you use this api for token validation `/validate_token` you have to send `uid, client, access_token`. Once your token is successfully  validated you will receieve a new token in the header, otherwise an error message.